# Codeplex SVN Access Error OPTIONS

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, codeplex

I've got a little frustrated at trying to get SVN to work with Codeplex. I thought it was a firewall in the office blocking it, fair enough, so started trying at home and get exactly the same error.

I'm trying to connect to some source on codeplex. I've tried the main [main](https://hg01.codeplex.com/greatmaps) branch and I've also tried my [Fork](https://hg01.codeplex.com/forks/ianwright83/serializableclasses) that I create through the site. Literally going to repository browser using TortoiseSVN and pasting in those URLs.

At home I disabled my firewall, and just have a router (with your standard setup) that connects me to the Internet. Tortoise constantly gives me the error:

> The OPTIONS response did not include
>   the request activity-collection-set;
>   this often means that the URL is not
>   WebDAV enabled

The main developer on the site can access it fine, so can lots  of other people. Question is why can't I? I've googled the error and all I come up with is stuff about proxy servers causing problems. I don't think I'm behind a proxy in either location (actually have no idea how to set one up).

Can anyone point out to me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have managed to resolve this issue. The Codeplex server wasn't an SVN server, instead it used Mercurial which requires using TortoiseHG instead.